# Combining similar shortcode functions?

Tags: shortcode

```
function customfield_1_shortcode( $atts ) {

            if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'customfield1', true ) ) {
        $customfield = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'customfield1', true );

    return "html stuff";
}
add_shortcode( 'customfield_1', 'customfield_1_shortcode' );

function customfield_2_shortcode( $atts ) {

            if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'customfield2', true ) ) {
        $customfield = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'customfield2', true );

    return "html stuff";
}
add_shortcode( 'customfield_2', 'customfield_2_shortcode' );
?>
```

I can use [customfield_1] to output customfield1 stuff, and [customfield_2] to output customfield2. What is the best way to combine these two or more functions like these (customfield_3, customfield_4 etc.) to achieve the similar effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do but perhaps something like this:

```
function customfields_shortcode( $atts ) {
  if (!empty($atts['field']) && get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $atts['field'], true ) ) {
    $customfield = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $atts['field'], true );
    return "custom field >> $customfield << custom field";
  }
}
add_shortcode( 'mycustomfields', 'customfields_shortcode' );

echo do_shortcode('[mycustomfields field="customfield_1"]');
```

One shortcode will handle all of your custom fields. Just pass in the field you want as an attribute (argument).